# Anonymity setup criticism

Tags: network, anonymity, tor

My current setup up is for pseudonymous communication on a smartphone. I need help to know if I am doing anything wrong.

- GrapheneOS
- all traffic over tor using (orbot)
- using Signal with anonymous number and conversations xmpp
- phone is strictly used for messaging only, nothing else, no browsing

I'm using a router, with a USB modem plugged into a router with a SIM in the modem. The device receives internet via ethernet cable.

Everything was bought anonymously. I'm more concerned about the network side of things, if I have done something incorrectly.

Is tower triangulation the only way to find location?

Comment: Geolocation is not anonymity. I'm afraid that you are trying to tackle too many problems at once and getting things confused.

Comment: Who do you want to hide from? What, exactly, do you want to hide?

Comment: "I'm using a router, with a USB modem plugged into a router with a SIM in the modem. The device receives internet via ethernet cable." -- what's connected to ethernet? The router? the phone? the modem?